# Please tell me how to set the spi channel and read the measured values

Tags: c, stm32, spi

I want to use the spi of stm32 to read several sensor measurements

How can I set up a channel?

I'm looking for it and using it, but I can't see it coming out properly. Please tell me

They say that you can use something like HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive for the sensor measurement, but I'm not sure about this, but I need to know how to set up a channel first

spi datasheet : https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8688.pdf?ts=1668384265698&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS8688%253Fdcmp%253Ddsproject%2526hqs%253Dpf

I made it by referring to the stm32 project here, but seeing that all the measurements are repeated, I don't know if I made it wrong or if it doesn't fit me
[enter link description here](https://github.com/obatsis/ADS8688-STM32)

Even if the sensor and the type of value (Voltage, temperature, etc) you measure are different, isn't it the same to read the measurements?

SPI_ADS_Init(&ads, &hspi2, GPIOB, 9);
I did it like this when I initialized it
There's nothing else besides changing the name of the variable

I did the following when I asked for the price

```
    SPI_ADS_Init(&ads, &hspi2, GPIOB, 9);
            for(;;)
          { 
            SPI_Read_All_Raw(&ads, ads_data);
              
            
          }
        HAL_StatusTypeDef SPI_Read_All_Raw(SPI_ADS *ads, uint16_t *data) {
            HAL_StatusTypeDef ret;
            uint8_t ads_raw[2];
            for(int i=0; i < CHNS_NUM_READ; i++) {
              ret = SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_CONT, ads_raw);
              data[i] = (int)((uint16_t)(ads_raw[1]<<8 | ads_raw[0]) >> 4);
                  
                  printf("%04X\n\r", data[i]);
            }
            return ret;
        }
uint8_t SPI_ADS_Init(SPI_ADS *ads, SPI_HandleTypeDef *spiHandle, GPIO_TypeDef *csPinBank, uint16_t csPin) {
    /* Store interface parameters in struct */
        ads->spiHandle      = spiHandle;
        ads->csPinBank  = csPinBank;
        ads->csPin      = csPin;
    
        uint8_t ads_data[2] = {0};
        uint8_t state = 0;
    
        // reset all registers to default
        state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_RST, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(100);
    
        // send a no_op message to the ADS to enter IDLE mode
        state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_CONT, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        // enable auto transmit for all inputs(datasheet page 54) or as many as you want
        // if you want only some of the inputs enabled, make sure to power down the unused ones
        ads_data[0] = 0xff;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_AUTO_SEQ_EN, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
            
        // set the desired features such as device id (if multiple devices are used), alarm enable/disable and output format
        ads_data[0] = 0x00; // here i chose id = 0, alarm = disabled and SDO_format = 3 (datasheet page 56)
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_FEATURE_SELECT, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x06;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_0, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x06;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_1, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x05;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_2, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x05;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_3, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x05;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_4, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x05;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_5, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x06;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_6, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        ads_data[0] = 0x06;
        state += SPI_Prog_Write(ads, SPI_CHN_RANGE_7, ads_data);
        HAL_Delay(10);
    
        // start the auto transmission by entering the appropriate state
        state += SPI_Cmd_Write(ads, SPI_AUTO_RST, ads_data);
    
        return state;
}
```

What I want to know is the source code for setting up the spi channel
Everyone wants me to look at the datasheet, but I don't know how to source it

Please let me know if the source code is the problem or if the channel setting is the problem

Measured value to be output

[image]

Comment: "Please let me know the channel setting source code, sites or blogs that I can refer to", you already has the library that you [linked to](https://github.com/obatsis/ADS8688-STM32), why don't you just download it and run the example (i.e. the `main.c`)? What else you need? Unless you don't want to use the library but to interface with the chip directly, then you need to read the datasheet and do it yourself, but based on your posts in the past, I think it is better to use the library until you are familiar with the STM32 and the ADS chip.

Comment: I'm going to write a function
I used the source code in the main, but the measurement came out weird

Comment: Have you configured your SPI peripheral as described in the README for the library you linked to?

Comment: When I used the code according to the previous setting, I repeated only two or three values as shown in the text, and when I set the spi setting in cubex as shown in the readme, there was no change from 0